# Updating swing components correctly

Tags: java, swing

I have been setting values on swing components just like I would any other variable, however I came across this page - https://bitguru.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/will-the-real-swing-single-threading-rule-please-stand-up/ - and it seems that I be making all changes to swing components using an event dispatching thread -

So, is this correct, should I change all the code where I updated swing components from this

```
    String name = this.getNameTextfield().getText();
    String password = new String(this.getPasswordField().getPassword());
    String confirmPassword = new String(this.getConfirmPasswordField().getPassword());
```

to this?

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               String name = this.getNameTextfield().getText();
               String password = new String(this.getPasswordField().getPassword());
               String confirmPassword = new String(this.getConfirmPasswordField().getPassword());
            }
        });
```

Is that the standard practise?

Edit: Oops, just copied and pasted some of my component related code, overlooked the fact that it wasnt updating componenets.

Comment: please note that my answer is not correct. the correct one is kleopatra's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case you do not modify any component, so you don't need to do it on the EDT, but when you do modify the UI, the second method is correct.

Answer (score 9):

The Swing bible has a [chapter on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), bottom line:

> all code that creates or **interacts** with Swing components must run on the event dispatch thread

(emphasis is mine)

So yes, you always have to ensure that all your access, reading or writing, happens on the EDT.

On the bright side: once the application is started correctly on the EDT, you already *are* on it and nearly all access naturally happens on the EDT. That's not the case only if you explicitly started another thread (f.i. for doing a lengthy background task) and need to report back into the ui: then you have to wrap the access calls into invokeLater (or use a SwingWorker which does so internally)

Comment: +1, I didn't knew, that reading should also be done on EDT :-)

Comment: You're right. This answer should be the accepted one. I cannot mine  as it was accepted. but anyway +1.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable - the following lines are pretty much equivalent

```
String password = new String(this.getPasswordField().getPassword());
String password = this.getPasswordField().getPassword();
```

You're not modifying the components.

If you were updating them, then only if the update was from another Thread. If for example you were updating a text field from a ActionListener attached to a button then it would be unnecessary as you're already on the Event-Dispatch-Thread.

For maximum correctness you should determine if you're on the EDT first.

```
Runnable update = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getNameTextfield().setText("foo");
    }
};
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    update.run();
} else {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(update);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just reading data from components then you probably don't need to do this. Most reads from Swing component properties are thread safe.

invokeLater should be used if you want to run code on the Event Dispatching Thread, which is generally the case when you actually want to update the GUI.

There's a [short little tutorial here regarding the use of invokeLater](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml).

In order to make your life simpler and minimise the risk of problems, I'd recommend making sure that any code that interacts with the Swing GUI runs on the EDT. As kleopatra rightly points out, the good news is that this happens pretty much automatically since all your event handling code will be called by the EDT.

Comment: @kleopatra, maybe you are right in theory, but in practice pretty much all reads from Swing component properties are in fact thread safe. After all, they are generally just simple accessor methods reading a single field....

Comment: yeah, it's one of those we'll-get-away-with-thread-unsafe-reads most of the time - mostly because there are no other threads :-)

Comment: it's a bit better than that, the reads actually *are* thread safe in this case :-) but I agree with your sentiment in general.